# Online Computer Algebra Systems?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for web apps for symbolic and numerical mathematics.

I am not interested in what could be considered advanced (pocket) calculators and I know that Google search and Wolfram Alpha can also be used for many types of calculation.

I am thinking of apps with capabilities similar to that of Maple/Mathematica/Matlab/Octave and so on. Not that they have to be *that* advanced, but some kind of worksheet with input/output, simple scripting (for loops, etc.) should be available. Plotting would also be nice.

I realize that such an app would require a lot from the servers (if many users where doing heavy calculations) but maybe somebody have found a solution?

The apps that I have found so far are these:

- An [online version](http://sciencesoft.at/bc/) of GNU's bc (they call it a demo, however).
- [Sage Notebook](http://www.sagenb.org/). Looks very promising.

Open source projects are preferred, even if not in a "mature" state.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Omega—Computer Algebra System Explorer](http://www.vroomlab.com).

[Here](http://www.vroomlab.com/nhome/qr.jsp) is a quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sage Online: [Sage Math](http://www.sagemath.org/) or [AXIOM and others here](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org)

Answer (score 0):

[Mathics](http://www.mathics.net/) has Mathematica-compatible syntax and functions.

Comment: Mathics looks like it's dead now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Octave Online](http://octave-online.net).  It supports interactive sessions as well as scripting and plotting for GNU Octave.  I am on the development team for Octave Online.

Answer (score 0):

pls try http://mathHandbook.com - online computer algebra system